# Como exportar como shapefile um polígono criado por drawPoly?

Tags: r

Criei um `shape` utilizando a função `drawPoly()` (pacote `raster`) que desenha manualmente o polígono. Ao término da seleção ele gera um `SpatialPolygon`, mas não consigo exportar por não ser um `SpatialPolygonDataFrame`. O que devo fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O pacote [rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) permite fazer isso através do comando `writeOGR()`.

Supondo que teu poligono esteja na variável `poly`, bastaria o seguinte comando: `writeOGR(obj = poly, dsn = 'NomeDoArquivo.shp', layer = 'NomeDoLayer', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile')`